# problems with one user

Tags: 14.04, users

I am an amateur. So there is nothing simple I should know.

Basically, I installed Linux on a my PC as windows 7 kept freezing just to give something a try. It worked. So my brother made me make him an account and it never worked. It is always leaving a black screen that required a hard crash. Then (after an infinite amount of complaints to parents) I tried to fix the problem and accidentally turned auto-login on his account and now Ubuntu boots straight to a black screen.

I've tried stopping auto-login, deleting his user, adding a password to it and several other things has given no success.

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance (for trying).

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities:

- boot from recovery mode (from there you can try to reverse what you previously did)
- pres ctrl-alt-f2 (or whatever combination works for you) and work from CLI mode (since my guess is that the fault for the the black screen is from GUI).

In both cases I would try to *exclude* the other account and try to recreate it from the CLI paying attention to the options (`man adduser`).

Of course, there's always the possibility of re-installing the whole thing, especially if you have separate home and root partitions.

Comment: Successfully changed password on his account. Thought this would bring me to login screen but now gnome just hangs on boot on that blue/green screen.

Comment: Ok, what exactly did you do to change his password? Again, I think the best option is not to change his password. It is to delete his account and re-create it.